# Tag merge request: [monotouch.dialog] and [monotouch-dialog]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I suggest that the [monotouch.dialog](/questions/tagged/monotouch.dialog) (91 questions) and [monotouch-dialog](/questions/tagged/monotouch-dialog) (154 questions) tags should be merged.

Comment: The actual [name of the project](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) is `MonoTouch.Dialog`, so I think monotouch-dialog should be merged into monotouch.dialog.